# Print solutions to 3-variable equation

Tags: java, recursion

I have an assignment to write a program that receives a number between `3` and `30` returns the number of solutions to the equation `x1+x2+x3 = num`, where `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` are numbers between `1` and `10`.

It also prints those solutions. For example for `num=5` it returns `6` and prints the following:

```
1 + 1 + 3
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 3 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 1
3 + 1 + 1
```

I am required to use recursion.

The complexity doesn't matter according to the question. I think I succeeded doing this with a complexity of 3^n (which is horrendous). However, it also has the same answers being counted multiple times, so it's an invalid answer.

```
public static int solutions(int num) {
    if (num <3 || num > 30)
        return 0;
    return solutions(num, 1, 1, 1);
}
public static int solutions(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3) {
    if (x1 > 10 || x2 > 10 || x3 > 10)
        return 0;
    int count, val1, val2, val3;
    if (x1 + x2 + x3 == num) {
        System.out.println(x1+" + "+x2+" + "+x3);
        count = 1;
    } else
        count = 0;
    val1 = solutions(num, x1+1, x2, x3);
    val2 = solutions(num, x1, x2+1, x3);
    val3 = solutions(num, x1, x2, x3+1);

    return count + val1 + val2 + val3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List<List<Integer>>` to ensure the repeated occurrences do not get printed. Whenever you print a line, add `List.of(x1, x2, x3)` to the list and increase the count by returning `1`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solutions(5));
    }

    public static int solutions(int num) {
        if (num < 3 || num > 30)
            return 0;
        return solutions(num, 1, 1, 1, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public static int solutions(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3, List<List<Integer>> list) {
        if (x1 + x2 + x3 == num) {
            if (!list.contains(List.of(x1, x2, x3))) {
                list.add(List.of(x1, x2, x3));
                System.out.println(x1 + " + " + x2 + " + " + x3);
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        return solutions(num, x1 + 1, x2, x3, list) + solutions(num, x1, x2 + 1, x3, list)
                + solutions(num, x1, x2, x3 + 1, list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
1 + 3 + 1
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 1 + 3
6
```

Comment: Shouldn't it return 2 if you do not count duplicates?

Comment: @RetoHöhener - No, here duplicate means duplicate sequence e.g. `1 + 2 + 2` and `1 + 2 + 2` are duplicate sequences. This is as per the requirement the OP had mentioned in the question.

Comment: That's not clear to me from the question. OP shows his attempt to return 6, but writes that it is incorrectly counting duplicates.

Comment: @RetoHöhener - OP has given an example and mentioned: `For example for num=5 it returns 6 and prints the following:
1 + 1 + 3
   1 + 2 + 2
   1 + 3 + 1
   2 + 1 + 2
   2 + 2 + 1
   3 + 1 + 1
`. This is what this solution does . The solution which I had posted originally (please check edit) had the problem that it was counting and printing even the duplicate sequences.

Comment: True, I thought that was supposed to be the output of his attempt. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm I would use is to start with:

n - 2 1 1

and then I would do a divide et impera approach. Basically, the simplest way to change the combination above is to take one from the first and add one to the second or third, so possible results are

n - 3 2 1

or

n - 3 1 2

You will always take an element from the first and you will always have exactly two cases. So, the number of cases is roughly (n - 2)^2. I say "roughly", because there will be some duplicates, for example

1 2 2

can be reached both from

2 1 2

and from

2 2 1

To handle the duplicates, detect duplicates and take them into account only once. For example you take a duplicate into account when you add to the center but not when you add to the rightmost number.